# Can the titles and each title be customized color?

Tags: java, android, html, listview

I have a list view and their titles in     `"index.txt"`
There are no problems so far.

I just need a code to make this    `"index.txt"`    work like HTML view

To color a title, bold, etc., something like that:

```
        listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
Index("index.txt");
```

Comment: Please try to be more explanatory.

Comment: I want to use `Html.fromHtml` as the list view.
Quite simply: headings in a text document all appear the same.
I want to put a color for a title, or make it bold.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ANSI color codes](https://dev.to/awwsmm/coloured-terminal-output-with-java-57l3), but it would depend on the OS and how you print the file.